# VS 2017 and MySQL: Updated MySQL.Data to 8.0.11.0 and None of My Queries Work

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2017

About an hour ago, I updated the MySQL.Data reference to the latest version.  Now, NONE of my queries work.

When I exit my application, I can see the following error in my Output Window:

`Error: 0 : The host 127.0.0.1 does not support SSL connections.`

I didn't change anything, much less anything related to SSL.  Also, the connection I'm using DOES support SSL "if available" (according to MySQL Workbench Connection Manager window.)

I tried going back to the previous version of MySQL.Data that I was using, but the problem still persisted.  So, I'm back with the latest version, banging my head on the desk, figuratively.

Edit:  I also tried deleting my connection, recreating it, and then restarting VS2017.  No luck...

Edit2:  Oh, yeah.  I also tried uninstalling and reinstalling the MySQL/NET Connector.  Again, no luck...

Any idea what's going on?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, easy solution.  Added

```
SslMode=none;
```

to the end of my connection string.

Found answer here: [Is there a way to connect to a MySQL database without ssl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50554578/is-there-a-way-to-connect-to-a-mysql-database-without-ssl?rq=1)

I'll gladly delete this question, if it's desired.  If it's thought that it may help others, I'll just as gladly leave it up.